# Linking PnetCDF, NetCDF-C and NetCDF-Fortran libraries for an earth system model

Tags: linker-errors, netcdf, mpich, cime

I am trying to work on an earth system model and I am new to this.
Currently, I am only trying to run a test case which is computationally less intensive.

My system is Ubuntu 20.04. I have built the required libraries in the following order - mpich, pnetcdf, zlib, hdf5, netcdf-c, netcdf-fortran, lapack and blas. The versions are as follows (my GCC and gfortran version is 9.4.0)
**mpich**-3.3.1, **pnetcdf**-1.12.3, **zlib**-1.2.13, **hdf5**-1.10.5, **netcdf-c**-4.9.0, **netcdf-fortran**-4.6.0,  **LAPACK** and **BLAS** 3.11. For building with Parallel I/O support I had followed the order Pnetcdf, then hdf5, then Netcdf-c and finally Netcdf-fortran while installing. All the libraries and packages were  installed properly without any error and with the same compiler that I'd be using for the model.

The issue that I am coming across now has to do with the linking of libraries (pnetcdf, netcdf-c and netcdf-fortran), more particularly the order, as indicated by the forum dedicated for the model.
At the end of the build for the model, when it is trying to create a single executable,it fails (collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status).
**The following is the command where it shows the errors**

```
mpif90 -o /home/ubuntuvm/projects/cesm/scratch/testrun11/bld/cesm.exe \
cime_comp_mod.o cime_driver.o component_mod.o component_type_mod.o \
cplcomp_exchange_mod.o map_glc2lnd_mod.o map_lnd2glc_mod.o \
map_lnd2rof_irrig_mod.o mrg_mod.o prep_aoflux_mod.o prep_atm_mod.o \
prep_glc_mod.o prep_ice_mod.o prep_lnd_mod.o prep_ocn_mod.o \
prep_rof_mod.o prep_wav_mod.o seq_diag_mct.o seq_domain_mct.o \
seq_flux_mct.o seq_frac_mct.o seq_hist_mod.o seq_io_mod.o \
seq_map_mod.o seq_map_type_mod.o seq_rest_mod.o t_driver_timers_mod.o \
-L/home/ubuntuvm/projects/cesm/scratch/testrun11/bld/lib/ -latm \
-L/home/ubuntuvm/projects/cesm/scratch/testrun11/bld/lib/ -lice \
-L/home/ubuntuvm/projects/cesm/scratch/testrun11/bld/lib/ -llnd \
-L/home/ubuntuvm/projects/cesm/scratch/testrun11/bld/lib/ -locn \
-L/home/ubuntuvm/projects/cesm/scratch/testrun11/bld/lib/ -lrof \
-L/home/ubuntuvm/projects/cesm/scratch/testrun11/bld/lib/ -lglc \
-L/home/ubuntuvm/projects/cesm/scratch/testrun11/bld/lib/ -lwav \
-L/home/ubuntuvm/projects/cesm/scratch/testrun11/bld/lib/ -lesp \
-L../../gnu/mpich/nodebug/nothreads/mct/noesmf/c1a1l1i1o1r1g1w1e1/lib \
-lcsm_share -L../../gnu/mpich/nodebug/nothreads/lib -lpio -lgptl \
-lmct -lmpeu  -L/home/ubuntuvm/CESM/lib -lnetcdff \
-Wl,-rpath=/home/ubuntuvm/CESM/lib -lnetcdf -lm -lnetcdf -lhdf5_hl \
-lhdf5 -lpnetcdf -ldl -lm -lz -Wl,-rpath=/home/ubuntuvm/CESM/lib \
-lpnetcdf -L/usr/local/lib -llapack -L/usr/local/lib -lblas \
-L/home/ubuntuvm/CESM/lib -lpnetcdf  -L/home/ubuntuvm/CESM/lib
```

**Below is a part of the errors** where libpio.a is a component library that is built before the above command

```
/usr/bin/ld: ../../gnu/mpich/nodebug/nothreads/lib/libpio.a(nf_mod.F90.o): in function `__nf_mod_MOD_pio_copy_att':
nf_mod.F90:(.text+0x31): undefined reference to `nfmpi_copy_att'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../gnu/mpich/nodebug/nothreads/lib/libpio.a(nf_mod.F90.o): in function `__nf_mod_MOD_def_var_md':
nf_mod.F90:(.text+0x3b5): undefined reference to `nfmpi_def_var'
/usr/bin/ld: nf_mod.F90:(.text+0x4fe): undefined reference to `nfmpi_def_var'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../gnu/mpich/nodebug/nothreads/lib/libpio.a(nf_mod.F90.o): in function `__nf_mod_MOD_pio_def_dim':
nf_mod.F90:(.text+0xab9): undefined reference to `nfmpi_def_dim'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../gnu/mpich/nodebug/nothreads/lib/libpio.a(nf_mod.F90.o): in function `__nf_mod_MOD_pio_redef':
nf_mod.F90:(.text+0xeb9): undefined reference to `nfmpi_redef'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../gnu/mpich/nodebug/nothreads/lib/libpio.a(nf_mod.F90.o): in function `__nf_mod_MOD_pio_enddef':
nf_mod.F90:(.text+0xff0): undefined reference to `nfmpi_enddef'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../gnu/mpich/nodebug/nothreads/lib/libpio.a(nf_mod.F90.o): in function `__nf_mod_MOD_pio_inq_dimlen':
nf_mod.F90:(.text+0x115c): undefined reference to `nfmpi_inq_dimlen'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../gnu/mpich/nodebug/nothreads/lib/libpio.a(nf_mod.F90.o): in function `__nf_mod_MOD_pio_inq_dimname':
nf_mod.F90:(.text+0x14c2): undefined reference to `nfmpi_inq_dimname'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../gnu/mpich/nodebug/nothreads/lib/libpio.a(nf_mod.F90.o): in function `__nf_mod_MOD_pio_inq_dimid':
nf_mod.F90:(.text+0x1821): undefined reference to `nfmpi_inq_dimid'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../gnu/mpich/nodebug/nothreads/lib/libpio.a(nf_mod.F90.o): in function `__nf_mod_MOD_inq_varnatts_vid':
nf_mod.F90:(.text+0x1c24): undefined reference to `nfmpi_inq_varnatts'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../gnu/mpich/nodebug/nothreads/lib/libpio.a(nf_mod.F90.o): in function `__nf_mod_MOD_inq_vardimid_vid':
nf_mod.F90:(.text+0x1fcc): undefined reference to `nfmpi_inq_vardimid'
```

**The libraries are linked as follows**

```
-L/home/ubuntuvm/CESM_Library/lib -lnetcdff -lnetcdf \
-Wl,-rpath=/home/ubuntuvm/CESM_Library/lib -lnetcdf -lm -lnetcdf -lhdf5_hl \
-lhdf5 -lpnetcdf -ldl -lm -lz -Wl,-rpath=/home/ubuntuvm/CESM_Library/lib -lpnetcdf
```

What am I doing wrong here? I would be grateful for any suggestions regarding the order of the libraries and would be happy to provide any other details that might be required.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What is missing in your question is the details of the compiler error message. How do you run the compilation command? Do you use `make`?

Comment: Actually, my model is CESM2.1.3.  which is driven by CIME that helps configure, compile and execute Earth system models. CIME consists of python scripts that I have to use. The workflow invokes the following scripts 1. 'create_newcase' to create a case, 2. 'case.setup' which creates Run and Exec directories and creates macros.make, component namelists, 3. case.build to build individual component libraries and model executable 4. case.submit runs the model. My issue right now is at the third step.

Comment: The error messages are for functions from libpnetcdf. Since -lpnetcdf occurs after -lpio on the command line, it would have been used unless it is incompatible. Did you built libpnetcdf yourself or are you using a library provided by the distribution? Note that parallel libs must be built with the same MPI compiler and MPI libraries as the code that uses them.

Comment: Yes I built libpnetcdf on my own and had also compiled everything using mpich (configure, make, make tests, make check, make ptest, make ptests and make install). There were no errors. I have checked for the missing symbols there using nm libpnetcdf.a. and I could find them there. Should I try changing the version of pnetcdf?

Comment: It looks like it would be difficult to reproduce your problem as your installation of CESM is not very portable. Even if dockerized it would require quite a bit of configuration. However there are reports of successful setup of CESM on Ubuntu. E.g. this [medium post](https://medium.com/@yonas.mersha14/installing-porting-running-community-earth-system-model-c5f6ebfc613e). Did you try to reproduce this configuration?

Comment: Yes I have tried to replicate this, infact I am still trying to build the same case, but it did not work out for my system. I wonder if it had anything to do with GCC version, or any library versions.

Comment: After examining carefully the instructions in the medium post, I would suggest several changes: use `make -j 8` instead of `make`, compile all libs with mpi compilers and enable parallel in hdf5 and parallel-netcdf4 in netcdf-c. Stick with system default OpenMPI or build MPICH before building any IO libraries. Install netcdf-c and netcdf-fortran into the same dir. And certainly run `make check` before `make install`, not after. It takes a couple of hours of wait for the libraries to compile.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will follow this and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is difficult to reproduce this specific error. It looks like the issue is with PNetCDF library that does not seem to contain some FORTRAN functions.

Here is a brief instruction for setting up CESM on Ubuntu with **OpenMPI** starting from scratch.

**Caveats:** This example is for Ubuntu 22.04 (Jammy) but should work on all recent Ubuntu versions. This is for GCC version 11.4. Switching from OpenMPI to MPICH might require certain changes.

It is based on a very detailed [post by Yonash Mersha](https://medium.com/@yonas.mersha14/installing-porting-running-community-earth-system-model-c5f6ebfc613e). It would be ok to compare the instructions below with the instructions in that post if some details seem missing.

Assume the hostname is `ubuntu-jammy`.

1. Install the necessary system packages and libraries

```bash
apt-get install -y gcc g++ gfortran build-essential cmake git \
subversion python-is-python3 perl vim python3-pip libxml2-utils unzip libopenmpi-dev
```

2. For OpenMPI tests configure the number of slots on your machine.
   Assume that you have 8 CPU cores. This number will be used below many times as argument to `-j` option for `make`.

```bash
echo "ubuntu-jammy slots=8" >> /etc/openmpi/opempi-default-hostfile
```

3. Download CESM and setup CIME

```bash
mkdir CESM
cd CESM
RUN git clone -b release-cesm2.1.3 https://github.com/ESCOMP/CESM.git my_cesm_sandbox
mkdir ~/.cime
export CIME_MODEL=cesm
mkdir -p cesm/inputdata
```

4. Some UCAR SVN servers are using either self-signed certificates or certificates from some unknown CA, so edit `my_cesm_sandbox/manage_externals/manic/repository_svn.py` around line 267 to add options to ignore unknown CA. This might introduce a vulnerability, so think twice.
   Make the SVN command look like this:

```
cmd = ['svn', 'checkout', '--non-interactive', '--trust-server-cert-failures=unknown-ca', '--quiet', url, repo_dir_path]
```

5. Checkout the model codes

```bash
./manage_externals/checkout_externals
```

Use `./manage_externals/checkout_externals -S` to check that all the necessary codes have been delivered.

6. Now build the IO libraries and Lapack. We shall assume that libraries for CESM will be installed under `$HOME/CESM/lib`.

```bash
CESM_LIB_DIR=$HOME/CESM/lib
ZLIB=$CESM_LIB_DIR/zlib
HDF5=$CESM_LIB_DIR/hdf5
NETCDF=$CESM_LIB_DIR/netcdf
PNETCDF=$CESM_LIB_DIR/pnetcdf
export ZLIB HDF5 NETCDF PNETCDF
```

7. Download and unpack **zlib**, **hdf5**, **netcdf-c**, **netcdf-fortran**, **pnetcdf**, **lapack**
8. To build zlib use the default settings:
   In the directory containing zlib sources

```bash
./configure --prefix=$ZLIB
make -j 8
make check
make install
```

9. **Important:** build HDF5 with parallel support
   In the directory containing HDF5 sources

```bash
CPPFLAGS="-I$ZLIB/include" LDFLAGS="-L$ZLIB/lib" \
CC=mpicc CXX=mpicxx ./configure --prefix=$HDF5 --with-zlib=$ZLIB --enable-hl --enable-fortran --enable-parallel
```

After configure check that parallel support is enabled:

```
        SUMMARY OF THE HDF5 CONFIGURATION
        =================================
...
Features:
---------
                   Parallel HDF5: yes
Parallel Filtered Dataset Writes: yes
              Large Parallel I/O: yes
              High-level library: yes
...
```

Now build, check, and install.

```bash
make -j8
make -j8 check
make install
```

10. Build NetCDF C bindings with Parallel-NetCDF4 support
    In the directory containing netcdf-c sources

```bash
CPPFLAGS="-I$HDF5/include -I$ZLIB/include" LDFLAGS="-L$HDF5/lib -L$ZLIB/lib" \
CC=mpicc CXX=mpicxx ./configure --prefix=$NETCDF --disable-dap --enable-parallel4
```

Make sure the correct options are enabled

```
# NetCDF C Configuration Summary
==============================
...
HDF5 Support:       yes
NetCDF-4 API:       yes
NC-4 Parallel Support:  yes
...
```

Now make,check, and install

```bash
make -j8
make -j8 check
make install
```

11. Build NetCDF FORTRAN bindings
    In the directory containing netcdf-fortran sources

```bash
CPPFLAGS="-I$NETCDF/include -I$HDF5/include -I$ZLIB/include" \
FFLAGS="-fallow-argument-mismatch -fallow-invalid-boz" \
LDFLAGS="-L$NETCDF/lib -L$HDF5/lib -L$ZLIB/lib" LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$NETCDF/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" \
CC=mpicc CXX=mpicxx FC=mpifort ./configure --prefix=$NETCDF
```

Check that Parallel options are configured as follows:

```
# NetCDF Fortran Configuration Summary
==============================
...
Parallel IO:                    yes
NetCDF4 Parallel IO:            yes
PnetCDF Parallel IO:            no
...
```

Now build, check, and install

```
make -j8 
make -j8 check
make install
```

12. Build PNetCDF
    Switch to the directory, containing pnetcdf sources

```
CPPFLAGS="-I$NETCDF/include -I$HDF5/include -I$ZLIB/include" \
FFLAGS="-fallow-argument-mismatch -fallow-invalid-boz" \
LDFLAGS="-L$NETCDF/lib -L$HDF5/lib -L$ZLIB/lib" \
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$NETCDF/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" \
CC=mpicc CXX=mpicxx FC=mpifort ./configure --prefix=$PNETCDF --enable-shared --enable-fortran --enable-profiling --enable-large-file-test --with-netcdf4
```

Run

```bash
make -j8
make -j8 tests
make check
make ptest
make ptests
make install
```

While `ptest` runs on 4 processors, you should have at least this number.
Do not worry if some ptests fail because your system does not have enough processors, as some tests require 10 processors for MPI or more.

13. Build and install LAPACK

Switch to the LAPACK source directory

```bash
make -j8 blaslib
make -j8 lapacklib
mkdir -p $LAPACK/lib
mv librefblas.a $LAPACK/lib/libblas.a
mv liblapack.a $LAPACK/lib/liblapack.a
```

14. Configure machine
    copy the following text to .cime/config_machines.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config_machines version="2.0">
 <machine MACH="ubuntu-jammy">
    <DESC>
      Example port to Ubuntu Jammy linux system with gcc, netcdf, pnetcdf and openmpi
    </DESC>
    <NODENAME_REGEX>ubuntu-jammy</NODENAME_REGEX>
    <OS>LINUX</OS>
    <COMPILERS>gnu</COMPILERS>
    <MPILIBS>openmpi</MPILIBS>
    <PROJECT>none</PROJECT>
    <SAVE_TIMING_DIR> </SAVE_TIMING_DIR>
    <CIME_OUTPUT_ROOT>$ENV{HOME}/cesm/scratch</CIME_OUTPUT_ROOT>
    <DIN_LOC_ROOT>$ENV{HOME}/cesm/inputdata</DIN_LOC_ROOT>
    <DIN_LOC_ROOT_CLMFORC>$ENV{HOME}/cesm/inputdata/lmwg</DIN_LOC_ROOT_CLMFORC>
    <DOUT_S_ROOT>$ENV{HOME}/cesm/archive/$CASE</DOUT_S_ROOT>
    <BASELINE_ROOT>$ENV{HOME}/cesm/cesm_baselines</BASELINE_ROOT>
    <CCSM_CPRNC>$ENV{HOME}/cesm/tools/cime/tools/cprnc/cprnc</CCSM_CPRNC>
    <GMAKE>make</GMAKE>
    <GMAKE_J>8</GMAKE_J>
    <BATCH_SYSTEM>none</BATCH_SYSTEM>
    <SUPPORTED_BY>me@my.address</SUPPORTED_BY>
    <MAX_TASKS_PER_NODE>8</MAX_TASKS_PER_NODE>
    <MAX_MPITASKS_PER_NODE>8</MAX_MPITASKS_PER_NODE>
    <PROJECT_REQUIRED>FALSE</PROJECT_REQUIRED>
    <mpirun mpilib="default">
      <executable>mpiexec</executable>
      <arguments>
        <arg name="ntasks"> -np {{ total_tasks }} </arg>
      </arguments>
    </mpirun>
    <module_system type="none" allow_error="true">
    </module_system>
    <environment_variables>
      <env name="NETCDF">$ENV{HOME}/CESM/lib/necdf</env>
      <env name="PNETCDF">$ENV{HOME}/CESM/lib/pnetcdf</env>
      <env name="OMP_STACKSIZE">256M</env>
    </environment_variables>
    <resource_limits>
      <resource name="RLIMIT_STACK">-1</resource>
    </resource_limits>
  </machine>
</config_machines>
```

Validate the XML file

```bash
xmllint --noout --schema $HOME/CESM/my_cesm_sandbox/cime/config/xml_schemas/config_machines.xsd $HOME/.cime/config_machines.xml
```

15. Configure compilers
    Put the following text to `.cime/config_compilers.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config_compilers version="2.0">

  <compiler>
        <LDFLAGS>
                <append compile_threaded="true"> -fopenmp </append>
        </LDFLAGS>
        <FFLAGS>
                <append>   -fallow-argument-mismatch -fallow-invalid-boz</append>
        </FFLAGS>
        <SFC>gfortran</SFC>
        <SCC>gcc</SCC>
        <SCXX>g++</SCXX>
        <MPIFC>mpifort</MPIFC>
        <MPICC>mpicc</MPICC>
        <MPICXX>mpicxx</MPICXX>
        <CXX_LINKER>FORTRAN</CXX_LINKER>
        <NETCDF_PATH>$ENV{HOME}/CESM/lib/nectdf</NETCDF_PATH>
        <PNETCDF_PATH>$ENV{HOME}/CESM/lib/pnectdf</PNETCDF_PATH>
        <SLIBS>
                <append>-L $ENV{HOME}/CESM/lib/nectdf/lib -lnetcdff -lnetcdf -lm</append>
                <append>-L $ENV{HOME}/CESM/lib/lapack/lib -llapack -lblas</append>
        </SLIBS>
</compiler>

</config_compilers>
```

Validate the xml file

```bash
xmllint --noout --schema $HOME/CESM/my_cesm_sandbox/cime/config/xml_schemas/config_compilers_v2.xsd $HOME/.cime/config_compilers.xml
```

16. Create a new case, set it up, and build it.

```bash
cd $HOME/CESM/my_cesm_sandbox
cime/scripts/create_newcase --case mycase --compset X --res f19_g16
cd mycase
./case.setup
./case.build
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I will try this and update.

Comment: @Aatreyee please comment if anything fails, I could reproduce it and add fixes to the post.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am starting out everything from scratch with your recommendations and will update on this. I do however, wanted to clarify whether I should work with OpenMPI or MPICH?

Comment: @Aatreyee I used OpenMPI for a number of reasons stemming from my past experience. If you are more comfortable with MPICH I think we could try that as well. But in any case I would recommend starting with the build of MPICH or OpenMPI that comes with the distribution until you are 100% confident that you know in what aspect your build is different from what comes with the machine.

Comment: Thank you very much. So, you recommend that I should install OpenMPI or MPICH from the linux distributions instead of building from source?

Comment: Yes I suggest installing libopenmpi-dev

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot. I am going to try this.

Comment: Thank you very much, the model build has now finished successfully.

Comment: I have been able to build different model configurations with the suggestions that you made. But when I tried to run another case which is a global case with much higher resolution, I started getting errors (However the build was successful). The errors are pointing to mpiexec. Can I post the issue in these comments or should I create a new question?

Comment: @Aatreyee I suggest creating a new question. Linking to this one in the post and also posting a link to the new question in the comments here.

Comment: Another question has been posted according to your suggestions with the details of the issue [mpi](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77535113/22886127)